# Postgres 9.4.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS fails to install properly

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I'm trying to install PostgreSQL 9.4.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.2. I'm using the packages from `apt.postgresql.org`.

The package installs but it fails running `pg_createcluster`. If I run manually, I get:

`Creating new cluster 9.4/main...
  config /etc/postgresql/9.4/main
  data /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main
  locale en_US.UTF-8
Flags of /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main set as --------------e-C
Error: initdb failed`

I can't find any details as to why `initdb` fails.

If I manually run `initdb` as the `postgres` user, that works, but that does not create the config files.

I checked everything I could think of, including on-line and can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an elegant solution but after installing the package using `apt-get` (which fails creating the cluster but installs PostgreSQL), I switched to the `postgres` user and created the database using `initdb`. Then back to `root`, I created the cluster using the `pg_createcluster` command.

This moved the configurations to `/etc/postgres/9.4/main` and set it all up.